# Pandora won't run in Tor browser

Tags: flash, browser, tor, pandora

I get an error message to update Flash which I have, tried updating browser and no luck.  Any suggestions?  I'm using Tor instead of Firefox or Chrome as a way around a firewall both of which block Pandora completely.

Comment: Have you enabled Flash inside Tor Browser? Please be aware that if you do this this could affect the anonymity the Tor Browser provides.